# dplyr dates saved in numeric format in sqlite

Tags: r, sqlite, dplyr, lubridate

I have a data frame that has a variable of dates and then I write it into a sqlite file, when I read the sqlite file again the date variable is in numeric format. Here is the code I'm using:

```
>BOR<-tbl(database, "BOR")
>BOR<-as.data.frame(BOR %>%
                     select(RTK,Date,Day))
```

with the following output:

```
>str(BOR)
'data.frame':   341549 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ RTK : num  59506 59506 59506 59506 59506 ...
 $ Date: num  17571 17571 17571 17571 17571 ...
 $ Day : chr  "viernes" "viernes" "viernes" "viernes" ...
```

To adress the date format I use a line and then write BOR again into the sqlite:

```
>BOR$Date<-as.Date(BOR$Date, origin = "1970-01-01")#format = "%Y-%m-%d")
>str(BOR)
$ RTK            : num  59506 59506 59506 59506 59506 ...
$ Date           : Date, format: "2018-02-09" "2018-02-09" "2018-02-09" "2018-02-09"
$ Day            : chr  "viernes" "viernes" "viernes" "viernes" ...
>copy_to(database, BOR, temporary = FALSE, overwrite = TRUE)
```

But when I read it again, it is again on numeric format.

```
>BOR<-tbl(database, "BOR")
>BOR<-as.data.frame(BOR %>%
                     select(RTK,Date,Day))
>str(BOR)
'data.frame':   341549 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ RTK : num  59506 59506 59506 59506 59506 ...
 $ Date: num  17571 17571 17571 17571 17571 ...
 $ Day : chr  "viernes" "viernes" "viernes" "viernes" ...
```

I'm lost at this issue, and I want to read the sqlite file and filter it by date ranges with our having to work with it as a data.frame convert the numeric format to date format and then filter the date range.

Comment: SQLite does not have any date type.  Use a different database.